# Custom gradient for broadcasting operation

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I have an operation for which I want to define a custom gradient with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient). The operation takes two broadcastable arguments and produces a result with the broadcasted shape. The problem is how to handle the broadcasting rules "backwards" in the custom gradient. Let's take the example for a multiplication operation from the documentation of [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def bar(x, y):
  def grad(upstream):
    dz_dx = y
    dz_dy = x
    return upstream * dz_dx, upstream * dz_dy
  z = x * y
  return z, grad
```

I can use this gradient alright for the non-broadcasting case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    a = tf.ones([5])
    b = tf.ones([5])
    tape.watch([a, b])
    c = bar(a, b)
# Works fine
grad_a, grad_b = tape.gradient(c, [a, b])
```

However, when the inputs are broadcasted, the result is not correct:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    a = tf.ones([10, 1])
    b = tf.ones([5])
    tape.watch([a, b])
    c = bar(a, b)
grad_a, grad_b = tape.gradient(c, [a, b])
print(grad_a.shape, grad_b.shape)
# (10, 5) (10, 5)
```

In fact, trying to use it in graph mode fails:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    a = tf.ones([10, 1])
    b = tf.ones([5])
    c = bar(a, b)
    grad_a, grad_b = tf.gradients(c, [a, b])
# ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.
```

Is there a way to handle this "unbroadcasting" of the input gradients automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Although not part of the public API, TensorFlow implements utilities for this purpose. In particular, there is a helper [`BroadcastGradientArgs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.12.0/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L1968-L1982) op type that calculates how you have to reduce and/or reshape the gradients of two broadcasting inputs. This is used internally by functions like [`GradForBinaryCwise`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.12.0/tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc#L394-L431) to simplify the definition of gradients.

At the Python level, there is [`tensorflow.python.ops.math_grad.SmartBroadcastGradientArgs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L63-L84), which essentially uses the same op but with some additional logic to save work when possible.

For example, for the case of a binary component-wise operation like multiplication, you can define the following helper:

```py
import functools
from typing import Callable, Tuple
import tensorflow as tf

def grad_for_binary_cwise(grad_fn: Callable[[tf.Tensor], Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]], x: tf.Tensor, y: tf.Tensor) -> Callable[[tf.Tensor], Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]]:
    """
    Helper to define custom gradients for binary broadcasting
    component-wise operations.
    Args:
        grad_fn: Base gradient function. This should accept the gradient of the
                 output and return the gradients of the two inputs, under the
                 assumption that both inputs and the output have the same shape
                 (i.e. no broadcasting was required).
        x: First input to the operation.
        y: Second input to the operation.

    Returns:
        A function that can be used as custom gradient for the broadcasting operation.
    """
    @functools.wraps(grad_fn)
    def wrapper(dz):
        from tensorflow.python.ops.math_grad import SmartBroadcastGradientArgs
        (sx, rx, must_reduce_x), (sy, ry, must_reduce_y) = SmartBroadcastGradientArgs(x, y, dz)
        dx, dy = grad_fn(dz)
        if must_reduce_x:
            dx = tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(dx, rx), sx)
        if must_reduce_y:
            dy = tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(dy, ry), sy)
        return dx, dy
    return wrapper
```

Then, you would simply define the custom gradient as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def bar(x, y):
    def grad(upstream):
        dz_dx = y
        dz_dy = x
        return upstream * dz_dx, upstream * dz_dy
    z = x * y
    return z, grad_for_binary_cwise(grad, x, y)
```

Now the gradient works as expected:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    a = tf.ones([10, 1])
    b = tf.ones([5])
    tape.watch([a, b])
    c = bar(a, b)
grad_a, grad_b = tape.gradient(c, [a, b])
print(grad_a.shape, grad_b.shape)
# (10, 1) (5,)
```